# Best practice to handle 'handleError ` and `extractData` private methods

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, observable

According to the [**Angular doc**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) the best way of handling observable as shown below.My question is, can you suggest me to a good coding practice to avoid usage of `handleError` and `extractData` private methods again and again on each and every service? How can I declare it once and use everywhere?

```
    getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
      return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                      .map(this.extractData)
                      .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
      // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
      let errMsg: string;
      if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
      } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
      }
      console.error(errMsg);
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
```

**Update:**

**handle-observable-service.ts**

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

export abstract class HandleObservableService {

  //to handle error
  protected handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

  //to extract data
  protected extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
  }
}
```

**authentication-data.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { HandleObservableService } from "../utility-services/handle-observable-service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationData extends HandleObservableService {
  authenticationEndPoint: string = "https://www.myk.com/admin/index.php?route=api/login&username=";

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    super();
  }

  //to login
  loginUser(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    let body = '';
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = this.authenticationEndPoint + encodeURI(username) + '&password=' + encodeURI(password);

    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }

}
```

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthenticationData } from "../../providers/authentication-data";
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {
  response: any;
  loginForm: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public authenticationData: AuthenticationData,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public storage: Storage, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required])]
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

  //to login
  loginUser(): void {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.authenticationData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password)
        .subscribe(data => {
          if (data.token != null && data.token != '') {
            this.storage.ready().then(() => {
              this.storage.set('token', data.token);
            });
            this.navCtrl.pop();
          } else {
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Error',
              subTitle: 'User Name or Password is wrong',
              buttons: [{
                text: 'OK',
                handler: data => {
                }
              },]
            });
            alert.present();
          }

        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        },
        () => console.log('Complete')
        );
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You can use base class where will be defined these methods

Comment: If you don't mind can you please do small code snippet explanation about it? @yurzui

Comment: By declaring it once and using it everywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create base class like:

**base.service.ts**

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

export abstract class BaseService {
   protected handleError (error: Response | any) {
      // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
      let errMsg: string;
      if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
      } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
      }
      console.error(errMsg);
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

  protected extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
}
```

and then `HeroService` will extend it:

**hero.service.ts**

```
import { BaseService } from './base.service';

class HeroService extends BaseService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    super();
  }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented it as shown above.But when I `subscribe` to the `observable` from different `ts` file where it doesn't return value which it extracted using `this.extractData` method.Do you know why? But it nicely extracted the value inside the `BaseService`.But seems it doesn't visible to the subscriber method.why's that?

Comment: can you please implement the `subscriber` part also?

Comment: It seems the `return body.data || { }` value is only visible within the `BaseService` class.It doesn't return to the `subscriber` method.How to solve that issue?

Comment: Did you try `heroServie.getHeroes().subscribe((data) =>`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that way.But the return value of the `extractData` method is `undefine`. In other words `heroServie.getHeroes().subscribe((data) =>` here `data` is `undefine`.Why?

Comment: It seems the issue is due to different `scope` or `context`.How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Create plunker to reproduce it

Comment: Yeah, on plunker it is working.It seems my implementation issue.Can you please see the update section.Where have I done wrong?

Comment: The only problem is within `login.ts` file. When I come to the `loginUser()` method, no value for the `data.token`.But value is there inside the `HandleObservableService` class.where am I wrong?

Comment: It is working fine when I use the inline methods without the base class.Can't you see any issue on my code base?

Comment: It is my Bad.There is no like this `return body.data || {};` on my response.It must be `return body || {};` I have done correctly it with inline methods.Here I just copied the doc's content.Thank you so much.This is awesome.Cheers :)